# Axes labels in importing NetCDF files

Tags: import

### Issue

I would like to get Mathematica's NetCDF functionality compatible with that
used in the Python package `xarray`.

First generate some dummy data.

```
# Code adapted from
# http://xray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/quick-overview.html
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)

times = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', name='time')
annual_cycle = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (times.dayofyear.values / 365.25 - 0.28))

base = 10 + 15 * annual_cycle.reshape(-1, 1)
tmin_values = base + 3 * np.random.randn(annual_cycle.size, 3)
tmax_values = base + 10 + 3 * np.random.randn(annual_cycle.size, 3)

# Notice that the axes of the 2D array tmin are labeled as time and location
ds = xr.Dataset({'tmin': (('time', 'location'), tmin_values),
                 'tmax': (('time', 'location'), tmax_values)},
                {'time': times, 'location': ['IA', 'IN', 'IL']})
ds.to_netcdf('example.nc', format='NETCDF3_CLASSIC')
# Use 'NETCDF3_CLASSIC' because the Mathematica documentation claims support
# only for version 3.
# http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/NetCDF.html
```

Now examine the file's contents.

```
>>> import xarray as xr
>>> xr.open_dataset('example.nc')
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (location: 3, time: 2)
Coordinates:
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02
  * location  (location) |S2 b'IA' b'IN' b'IL'
Data variables:
    tmin      (time, location) float64 -8.037 -1.788 -3.932 -9.341 -6.558 0.132
    tmax      (time, location) float64 -2.061 3.933 9.017 2.578 3.141 4.894
```

Notice that in data variables, `tmin` has (time, location) noted as the axes
labels, which means that the file has actually encoded this information.

By default, Mathematica does not understand these axes labels (or if it does, it isn't telling me).

```
Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "example.nc", "Rules"]

{"Annotations" -> {{"_FillValue" -> Indeterminate}, {"_FillValue" -> 
     Indeterminate}, {"units" -> "days since 2000-01-01 00:00:00", 
    "calendar" -> "proleptic_gregorian"}, {}}, 
 "Data" -> {{{-8.03737, -1.78844, -3.93154}, {-9.34116, -6.55807, 
     0.132037}}, {{-2.06052, 3.93278, 9.01733}, {2.57751, 3.14107, 
     4.8936}}, {0, 1}, {"IA", "IN", "IL"}}, 
 "DataFormat" -> {"Real64", "Real64", "Integer32", "String"}, 
 "Datasets" -> {"tmin", "tmax", "time", "location"}, 
 "Dimensions" -> {{2, 3}, {2, 3}, {2}, {3}}, "Metadata" -> {}}
```

However, I want the axes labels to be available in Mathematica.

One possibility is that I might have to write a custom importer for this
(based on the existing one). I did find an official
[tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html)
describing the process of creating a custom importer, but I'm lost on how to
proceed as the tutorial doesn't really discuss leveraging an existing format.

### Digging

Using the Python package [`netCDF4`](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/)
(used internally by `xarray`), we can examine the structure of the file before
it is cast by `xarray`:

```
>>> from netCDF4 import Dataset
>>> ds = Dataset("example.nc", "r", format="NETCDF3_CLASSIC")
>>> print(ds)
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>
root group (NETCDF3_CLASSIC data model, file format NETCDF3):
    dimensions(sizes): time(2), location(3), string2(2)
    variables(dimensions): float64 tmin(time,location), float64 tmax(time,location), int32 time(time), |S1 location(location,string2)
    groups:
```

Comparing the `variables` line above with the `"Dimensions"` line in Mathematica output
suggests that Mathematica might be substituting the dimensions values of time and
location (located in the `dimensions` line) when trying to compute the `"Dimensions"`
for `tmin` and `tmax`.

If that is being done internally, it would be nice if we could somehow prevent
the substitution from happening and get the axes labels directly.
That would avoid a lot of work involved in writing a custom importer.

Comment: I just realised that there is a simple workaround by fiddling with the Python source: we can another field like `"tmin_axes" : ["time", "location"]` in the `xarray` dataset and save that. Since Mathematica has no issues with getting the data, we can assign the axes using this information.

Comment: hi! do you have any recommendation on how to get a similar functionality to that of xarray in mathematica? like slicing by index, position, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Mathematica 13.0 one can import axes (dimensions) labels directly with "DimensionNames" element:

```
In[1]:= Import["ExampleData/precipitation.nc", "Datasets"]

Out[1]= {"/ANOMALY", "/lat", "/lon"}


In[2]:= Import["ExampleData/precipitation.nc", "DimensionNames"]

Out[2]= <|"/ANOMALY" -> {"lat", "lon"}, "/lat" -> {"lat"}, "/lon" -> {"lon"}|>
```

The extent of each dimension can be imported as before with "Dimensions" element:

```
In[3]:= Import["ExampleData/precipitation.nc", "Dimensions"]

Out[3]= <|"/ANOMALY" -> {90, 180}, "/lat" -> {90}, "/lon" -> {180}|>
```